# Swift 2 - Extra argument in call

Tags: ios, swift

I've created a error handling class, which is suppose to make my calls easier, however i keep getting an error `Extra limit argument in call`. I've double checked that their is 7 arguments in both, how come i get this error?

**Class**

```
class GetOrganization {

  func request(
  lastPage: Int?,
  limit: Int,
  location: CLLocation,
  radius: Int?,
  success successCallback: (JSON) -> Void,
  error errorCallback: (statusCode: Int) -> Void,
  failure failureCallback: (error: Error) -> Void
  ) {


      Provider.request(.Organizations(lastPage, limit,location.coordinate.longitude, location.coordinate.latitude, radius)) { result in
          switch result {
          case let .Success(response):

              do {
                  try response.filterSuccessfulStatusCodes()

                  let json = try JSON(response.mapJSON())
                  successCallback(json)


              }
              catch {
                  errorCallback(statusCode: response.statusCode)
              }



          case let .Failure(error):
              failureCallback(error: error)

          }
      }
  }

}
```

*Where i get the error**

```
    GetOrganization.request(
            lastPage: lastPage,
            limit: limit,
            location: location,
            radius: nil,
            success: { data in

                }, error: { err in
                    print(err)
                }, failure: { faillure in
                    // oh well, no network apparently
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not a static function, so you can't call it like `GetOrganization.request`. Either set the `func request` as `static func request` or create an object and access it via that object.